# How can I render a font-face consistently in all browsers

Tags: html, css, font-face

So I have some problems with Helvetica Neue, if I set the font-size to 15px it will work, but if it's bigger than 16 or so...it looks....kind of weird.

Here you can see, how it should look like: http://screencast.com/t/hmK7dvzKt3ch

And here you can see the problem: http://latest-mtv.net/evidence/page2.php

Any solutions?

Best Regards,

Comment: What is up with the baseline on some of those characters?  I can't believe that the image you linked is actually how it's **supposed** to look.

Comment: I don't know..that's what i'm trying to find out..

Comment: Debug on Chrome is reporting that the font is in fact using HelveticaNeue, but it certainly isn't looking correct!  Neue is a favorite of print designers I've worked with and has never translated well to the web in my experience.

Comment: Hmmm, and is there any work-around?

Comment: "All browsers"? Looks fine in Opera 11.10 on my WinXP laptop. All I can suggest is that you remove `helveticaneue-webfont.svg#HelveticaNeueRegular` and `?#iefix` from your CSS rules and try again with the affected browsers.

Comment: You're not permitted to use Helvetica Neue in @font-face rules anyway. Its license doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 0):

The screen shots have expired but it sounds very much like something I've often seen before.

Visit cloudconvert.com and convert your font to a .woff file.
Either from your site resources (.svg?) or find the .ttf on your system.
Save the .woff file in your website root folder, somewhere.
In the css create a font-face entry:

```
@font-face
{
 font-family:'myawesomefont';
 src:url('../<path to .woff file>/convertedhelvneue.woff') format('woff');
}
```

Add the following line to the css selector:

```
.myawesomeclass
{
  font-family:myawesomefont;
  font-size:16px;
}
```

Once it's working, you might like to look into licences before you publish your work.
I hope this helps.